# Converting PDF Byte Array to jpg image(JAVA Project)

Tags: java, api, pdf, jpeg

We are trying to convert PDF Byte Array to image(jpg format) in a JAVA project. 
We initially used PDFBox library but we are facing issues with the output. The generated PDF documents generated by PDFBox are ok but sometimes the images generated are blank.

Can anyone suggest some reliable and robust PDF libraries for JAVA. We are mainly looking for open source libraries but licensed libraries are also an option.

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/210029/821436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opensource Libraries

http://www.jpedal.org/
https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/
http://code.google.com/p/pdfonejava/

Commercial Libraries,
http://www.qoppa.com/pdfimages/index.html
http://www.crionics.com/

I would prefer using jpedal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a command line tool on Linux you can use from ImageMagick

```
convert file.pdf file.png
convert file.pdf file.jpeg
```

Can you stream your bytes through convert? Or write to tempfile and then convert?